# Can't fetch the index number of repeated character in a string

Tags: kotlin

[Kotlin 1.3.31]
I am trying to print number of times each char in a string repeats on the right position but because of repeating char I cant fetch the index of the second occurrence of that char

I tried the indexOf with position specified as the last index ,and now the error is occurring for consecutive repeats only

```
var Last=0
for (Left in str){
    var num:Int=-1

    var index=str.indexOf(Left,Last)

        for (i in index..len)
        if (Left.equals(str[i],true)) {
            num++
        }
    Last=index
        println("The Char $Left repets $num Times on the right")
    }
```

Comment: what does it mean 'on the right position' ?

Comment: I'm not sure what this is asking, either.  Can you post some sample input and the corresponding output you want?  (Also, you'll get better highlighting — and less confusion! — if you start all variables with a lower-case letter, which is the standard.)

Comment: In String "ABCD"  "BCD" are on the right position  of "A"

Comment: what did your mean about right position??
did you mean correct position in alphabet order ????